# How do I put a form the middle of a form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an application that sends information to the server

**example:**

```
<form1>
    first name: (textbox)
    last name: (textbox)
    stuff: (textbox)
    [submit]
</form1>
```

how do i put a form in the middle of the form so that its something like this?

```
<form1>
    first name: (textbox)
    last name: (textbox)
</form1>

<form2>
    information: (text)
    [submit2]
</form2>

<form1>
    stuff: (textbox)
    [submit1]
<form1>
```

so that if i press submit1, the form sends (stuff, first name, last name)...

if i press submit2, the form sends (information)

Comment: you can submit through js according to the which submit button pressed

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an iframe, where the 2nd form is actually on a completely separate page. And you can pass stuff to that embedded iframe from the parent using $_GET or $_SESSION variables.

If you submit the iframe form and you want that action/data to affect the parent page's form when it's submitted, just save the iframe's form data results as a SESSION variable(s) and then reference that SESSION data (if it exists) on the page that your parent page form submits to.